# GROUP BY doesn't return all rows per specific field

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the DB :

Account table

[image]

With the records :

[image]

Clients table

[image]

with the records :

[image]

I want to get all the clients' names & id , that are in Overdraft organized by client ID , so :

```
SELECT c.Client_id_number , a.Account_number ,  c.firstName_client , c.lastName_Client , a.Account_balance
FROM Clients AS c 
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a
ON a.Client_id_number = c.Client_id_number
WHERE a.Account_balance < 0
GROUP BY c.Client_id_number;
```

But this returned

[image]

Meaning the client `1234` with account `84` , and balance `-4000` doesn't appear ... where did I go wrong ?

Comment: why dont u take a sum(a.Account_balance) and then do group by ? since group by without aggregation will only select one row !!

Comment: Why do you group by something at all if you want to see all matching records? Remove the group by clause and you are done.

Comment: Hi ron, I think you should look for tutorials on GROUP BY on the Internet, so you know exactly what it does. There are usually good examples with tables emp (or employee) and dept (or department). Then read on MySQL GROUP BY enhancement (which is: you don't need to specify each column in the GROUP BY clause or aggregate it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** Firstly, I should make clear the following, you dont need to use the "group by" because you are not summarizing, so your query should be:

```
SELECT c.Client_id_number , a.Account_number ,  c.firstName_client , c.lastName_Client , a.Account_balance
FROM Clients AS c 
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a
ON a.Client_id_number = c.Client_id_number
WHERE a.Account_balance < 0
```

I noticed that you have problems with the "group by" concept, so it is important that you know that you need to group by each field within your "SELECT" excepting by those where you are summarizing (c.Client_id_number , a.Account_number)

so, i.e.

```
SELECT c.Client_id_number , a.Account_number,  sum(a.Account_balance) as balance
FROM Clients AS c 
INNER JOIN Accounts AS a
ON a.Client_id_number = c.Client_id_number
WHERE a.Account_balance < 0
GROUP BY c.Client_id_number, a.Account_number;
```

Comment: Sorry to say this, but this statement is junk in my eyes. What is group by supposed to do here? Client_id_number and account_number should be unique anyhow, so group by doesn't do anything.

Comment: I know, but it was his question, maybe is not easy at all for him to understand "Group by" concept, so I explained him and I resolved his doubt.

Comment: I agree with @ThorstenKettner; this is not a good statement.  Someone who does not understand `GROUP BY` is the person who most needs a *clear and correct* example.

Comment: you are right, thank you for the correction, I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are only grouping by `client_id_number`, which means you will only get one row per client ID.

You need to group by *the set of rows that you want to be unique in the output*.  In this case, that probably means:

```
GROUP BY c.Client_id_number, a.account_number
```

And then you should apply an aggregate function to any column that is not part of the grouping, such as `sum(account_balance)`.

If you are not using any aggregate functions, it is an indication that you don't actually need grouping.

In most databases it is an error to select any columns that were not in the group by statement, but MySQL "helpfully" allows this kind of query.  Instead of returning an error, it hides the problem and randomly picks a possible value for the remaining columns.

Answer (score 1):

The GROUP BY statement is used in conjunction with the aggregate functions (for example SUM) to group the result-set by one or more columns.
If not doing any aggregation then use ORDER BY